# remembering what $(this) is

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script which changes a jquery made object's color to blue:

```
$(".objects_list").live('click', function(event)
{
    $(this).css("color", "blue");
});
```

How do I remember what $(this) is so I can change the color again but from a different function or from an event of a different object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of a global variable, you can use jQuery's [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method to associate information with the document itself:

```
$(".objects_list").live('click', function(event) {
    $(this).css("color", "blue");
    $(document).data("yourObjectKey", $(this));
});
```

Then you can easily get that information later:

```
$("otherSelector").click(function() {
    var yourObject = $(document).data("yourObjectKey");
    if (yourObject != null) {
        yourObject.css("color", "red");
    }
});
```

**EDIT:** If the element is destroyed and recreated between the two events, that method won't work. In that case, you can store the element's `id` instead of a reference to the element itself:

```
$(".objects_list").live('click', function(event) {
    $(this).css("color", "blue");
    $(document).data("yourObjectKey", this.id);
});
```

Then:

```
$("otherSelector").click(function() {
    var yourObjectId = $(document).data("yourObjectKey");
    if (yourObjectId != null) {
        $("#" + yourObjectId).css("color", "red");
    }
});
```

Comment: This is what I would do. You're probably better off without a global variable.

Comment: what if you first click otherSelector , before you eaven touch .object_list ? how does it handle ? does it trigger an error or ... ? i never tought you could do this .

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: I can't get this to work for some reason.  What happens is the object is created, if I select the object, it changes blue, but that object can later get destroyed and created again.  If the object is later created again and was previously selected, it should retain its color, but it doesn't.

Comment: @poelinca, good point, it would raise an error. I added a `null` test to my answer.

Comment: @oshirowanen, if the object gets destroyed, all bets are off, since the reference stored in `data()` won't be part of the document anymore. In your case, it might be best to store the element id instead. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: Thanks, I will have to modify my original script to create an id for each of the objects.

Comment: Frederic, what if the element does not have an ID? I usually test for one and add one if I need it's reference (using a random number).

Comment: My answer is better, simpler.

Comment: Oops, I didn't see oshirowanen's comment. I would still add the ID check and add to the answer, though.

Comment: @Jared, the `id` is the only attribute that's guaranteed to be unique, so... selecting on another attribute (like `name` or `class`) would be less reliable.

Comment: I didn't suggest selecting it by another attribute. What if the element doesn't have an id given? My suggestion is to add a check and if ($(this).attr('id') == '') $(this).attr('id','this_id_goes_here_123').

Comment: @Jared, then you would have to maintain a running counter in *another* `data()` key, in case you have to do that to more than one element :)

Comment: No. This is relying the this.id not being null or empty: $(document).data("yourObjectKey", this.id); If it is, then it won't work. Maybe it's known to be declared elsewhere. But saying you would need to store another piece of data is not true, since what I am suggesting is checking that this.id is not empty and adding one if not.

Comment: @Jared, we do agree about that, I was only saying that generating a unique `id` attribute on the fly is not that simple in the general case :)

Answer (score 2):

set an out of scope variable to be the object.

```
var thisObj;
$(".objects_list").live('click', function(event)
{
    thisObj = $(this);
    $(this).css("color", "blue");
});
```

Comment: Will this work even if $(this) is from an object created by javascript, i.e. an object added to DOM after the page has loaded?

Comment: as long as its an object when the click is clicked (which considering the context is a truism)

Answer (score 1):

```
var lastObj = null;
$(".objects_list").live('click', function(event)
{
    $(this).css("color", "blue");
    lastObj = $(this);
});

some_other_function()
{
    if ( lastObj != null )
        lastObj.css("color", "red");
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work.  Is it because $(this) is added later to DOM by javascript?

Comment: doesn't matter , if you test in some_other_function if lastObj was set it will work , it whont change the color from green to red for example if you didn't whent atleast once thru color blue change .

Comment: You probably don't want to use a global variable. Use $.data instead. See Frederic's and jAndy's answers.

Comment: why whouldn't i whant to use a global variable ? could you explain some good reasons for it ?

Comment: Because in other parts of your code or some other library you include could have a clash - and accidentally overwrite one piece of data with another. Not to mention, lastObj isn't particularly specific, so I would use a more deliberate/descriptive key, maybe "_objects_list_ref".

Comment: it's just an example , hence `some_other_function` name too . maybe using `jQuery.data( element, key, value )` will clash too wouldn't it ?

Comment: It's possible; thing is, you just don't need a variable in global scope, and the way you name that variable/key is important. :) To each their own, I would just use $.data.

Comment: i still don't understand why i shouldn't need a global variable , it's easyer to access ( type ) , tough in some way better to use $.data to act sort of like a namespace . I would have multiple global objects .

Comment: Some approaches consider it polluting the global variable namespace. I'm not saying your answer is wrong, it's just not what I would do. :) For reference, some pros and cons: http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad

Answer (score 1):

You could add an id attribute to indicate the "clicked" item, then other functions could select on that id. No need for global variables of any kind:

```
$(".objects_list").live('click', function(event)
{ 
    $(this).css("color", "blue");
    $('#objects_list_clicked').removeAttr("id");
    $(this).attr("id", "objects_list_clicked");
});
```

Comment: Why do you have to have to remove the ID attribute to change it?

Comment: I am a asssuming this is one object in some list of objects, so that call is first removing the previously clicked item's ID. I could be mistaken though.

Answer (score 0):

Could you attach an event listener to "$(this)" to listen for when the color should be changed back?

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest solution, but you could assign it to a global variable:

`myElement = $(this);`

Answer (score 0):

One option would just be to save $(this) in a variable:

```
var saved;
$(".objects_list").live('click', function(event)
{
    $(this).css("color", "blue");
    saved = $(this);
});
```

Comment: Will this work even if $(this) is from an object created by javascript, i.e. an object added to DOM after the page has loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Try it Differently:

```
$(".objects_list").live('click', function(event)
{
    var $this = $(this);
    $(".objects_list").removeAttr('selected');
    $this.attr('selected','selected');
        $this.css("color", "blue");
});
```

Now your selection is not stroed as javascript varible but in DOM.
You can change the setting anytime you want and from anywhere using followign code

```
if($(".objects_list").attr('selected').length != 0){
    var selectedTab = $(".objects_list").attr('selected');
}
```